# Android Studio: How to wrap code in parenthesis

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, dart, flutter

Is there any shortcut to wrap the Widget in the parenthesis.

**This is what it looks now**
[image: This is what it looks]

**This is how I want it to look**
[image: This is how I want it to look]

I know that we can use `cmd + .` to do that, but next time I open Android Studio, then again I have to do that over and over again. It simply lost its state.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any shortcut to wrap the Widget in the parenthesis.

`cmd + .` works well, but to answer to your question, yes there is another shortcut to folder current code block which is `cmd + -` or `cmd + .` if nothing selected.

`cmd + .` can be used for selected code in your case if it doesn't folder or doesn't keep the state of the editor that may be an issue with your android studio.

Comment: `cmd + -` is only used to wrap the scope `{}` not the parenthesis `()`